Element not clickable while scraping page with selenium
I'm trying to scrape this website: https://www.lavoro.gov.it/ and I have a problem when i search for a keyword in the searchbar and I get to the following page:

Now as you can see, I'm trying to cicle the pages in the website by auto-clicking with selenium on the arrow, but whenever I copy an XPATH linked to the arrow I get the following: #it-block-italiagov-content and the exception
[DEBUG] Exception: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
Here is my code, I've tried all differents XPATH:
        try:
            next_page_link = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "")
            # search_results_url = next_page_link.get_attribute("href")
            # driver.get(search_results_url)  # <--- open next page with results using URL
            next_page_link.click()   # <--- or click link 
        except Exception as e:
            print('[DEBUG] Exception:', e)
            print('[DEBUG] break')
            #input('Press ENTER to continue')
            break  # exit loop

Is there a way to bypass this?

driver.find_elements - this returns a list of web elements. You cannot perform click() on a list unless you loop into each of the item in the list and click it.
Hence the exception - 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
Change it to - driver.find_element
Code should be:
next_page_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@rel='next']")
next_page_link.click()

